# Starting Activity from a notification - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

I am trying to start an activity from a notification. Upon starting that activity, I add data via intent.putextra to the intent so the activity shows the right content for the situation.

The activity that is being started is supposed to be open only once in the stack. I did achieve this via

android:launchMode="singleTop"

in my manifest.

However - and now I come to my question - if this activity is already running, I want it to close and replace it with the instance I am creating with the specific additional data (put extra). How can I achieve this?

Heres the code of my notification:

```
public void newMessageNotification(String title, String message, String otherusernumber, String requestStatus, String sendername) {


        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

        Intent chatIntent = new Intent(this,ChatActivity.class);

        //these three strings define the behaviour of the chat activtity

        chatIntent.putExtra("otherUsername", sendername);
        chatIntent.putExtra("otherUsernumber", otherusernumber);
        chatIntent.putExtra("requestStatus", requestStatus);


        chatIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), chatIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);;


        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_new_message)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

Add **PendingIntent** in notification

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OpenActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Full create notification code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OpenActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager . getDefaultUri (RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Notification notification;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // The id of the channel.
            String Ch_id = "yourappname_01";
            // The user-visible name of the channel.
            CharSequence name = "Notification";
            // The user-visible description of the channel.
            //String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager . IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(Ch_id, name, importance);
            mChannel.setSound(defaultSoundUri, new AudioAttributes . Builder ().build());
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            // Create a notification and set the notification channel.
            notification = new Notification . Builder (this, Ch_id)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) //Add PendingIntent
                .setChannelId(Ch_id)
                .build();
        } else {
            // Create a notification
            notification = new Notification . Builder (this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) //Add PendingIntent
                .build();
        }
        //Generate Diff Notification
        int m =(int)((new Date ().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        notificationManager.notify(m, notification);
```

**Update**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OpenActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the flags you are suggesting but no help so far. When I first open the activity from this notification it works fine. But then, when I tap another notification and try to open this activity again, but with different data, I simply get back to the old one which is not suitable. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: see my notification code, I added it to the question. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Try to add flag: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to your `Intent`

Answer (score 0):

Try Below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityDestination.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); 

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

//pendingIntent  = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```